Unspecific "An error occured, please try again" when uploading animated GIF (supposedly supported)
When I try to upload an animated GIF that is smaller than 2MB, the uploader UI gives me the unspecific error message "An error occured, please try again".
I've tried multiple times, I always get this very same error.

Is this a bug in the uploader?
If it is intended behaviour, what is triggering the error? What am I doing wrong? Is the description no longer correct that animated GIFs are supported?

I would love to show an animated GIF showing the bug, but of course, this very issue prevents me from sharing that GIF (at least natively). Instead I'll give a screenshot:
This is the GIF I'm trying to upload, it's clearly <2MB:



This is me uploading said GIF:



This is the error I get:



I checked the console for errors as Ryan M suggested, but there are none. No error.
I don't think it's a duplicate of the SE Meta. There, the bug is supposedly fixed and also the error message is supposed to be more helpful when a megapixel limit is triggered.
I tried to upload a tiny GIF. That works! So it does seem to be that there's a megapixel limit (that must be stated in the description, or at least when the error is triggered). (Actually this is a megavoxel limit if you think of each frame as the 3rd dimension).
Please add the exact megapixel/voxel limit to the uploader. As it seems to be tighter than the MiB limit it's more important.


SE duplicate: Uploading a gif doesn't work on some SE sites

If you observe the network via your browser's developer tools, you'll most likely see an error message complaining that you're hitting the resolution limit (which is rather low for animated GIFs due to counting every frame), but it doesn't display for some reason.  I've hit that in the past and just hadn't gotten around to reporting it.

When did support for animated gifs actually role out? They were initially not supported and that post is still [[meta-tag:status-review]]; could it be the feature is still rolling out but the modals have been updated?

According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/399146/369403, if it's the megapixel limit, it should have a better error message

@RyanM I checked the console. No errors there.

Ok, uploading tiny animated gif works. Question updated.

Can you please host the original gif that SE fails to upload on a different place and link to it? Would like to try and reproduce, and also essential if developers would want to fix it.
